# Compare row by row in ResultSets, eliminating equals and displaying differences in between rows difference descending

Tags: java, database, dictionary, resultset

```
private Map<String, List<Object>> resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>(columns);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
        map.put(md.getColumnName(i), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            map.get(md.getColumnName(i)).add(rs.getObject(i));
        }
    }

    return map; }
```

I am using the above code to store results of my resultSets into a Collection. There are two SQL Queries generating two different resultSets and different amount of rows.  I would like to write a code which would eliminate rows which equal, and would print rows paired based on the least amount of differences in them. The columns which differ should be braced in square brackets.

Could anyone help with this one?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you want to eliminate identical rows from resultset? write query as such you dont get similar rows.

Comment: I will have two Map<String, List<Object>>, where i would like to compare each row to each row. And would oly like to see rows which do differ to each other. Not those which are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement there is no need of two Map. You can create a class to represent your table and create a list of that class, something like this:

```
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
SomeClass s = null;
 while (rs.next()) {
s = new SomeClass();
s.name =  rs.getString(1);
.......
list.add(s);
    }
```

Then you can add comparator to this class and decide which columns you want to be sorted.

Comment: I don’t know how would the structure of the result look like. The method should be dynamic. Meaning able to display different rows between different types of resultSets. Please correct me if I am wrong. But I think that I would need to know what output to expect before creating a class and then implementing a comparator.